# Is there a QML element to notify the Accessibility tree when a state has changed?

Tags: c++, qt, accessibility

My window has a transition from a "Pending" State to a "Success" state and needs to be Accessible for blind people.

IE:
Button Clicked -> "Pending" View with a spinner -> "Success" View with some text elements.

Is there a way to notify the accessibility tree to automatically update what has focus?

I've tried setting a `Text` element as `Accessible.focusable:true` and setting  the `Accessible.focused:true` but this does not bring focus to the `Text` element

```
Text { 
      id: successText
      text: "Success text"
      Accessible.text: "Success text"
      Accessible.focusable:true
}
....
PropertyChanges { target: successText; Accessible.focused: true; }
```

On success, Narrator should be focused on the Success Text and ideally the Success Text should be read

Comment: i'm not sure about qml, but in straight html, you use the `aria-live` attribute (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) to tell the screen reader that something changed.  perhaps there's a similar qml property.